# URLs like https://example.com/page.html?param=val in offline PWA

Tags: url, caching, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

I did not think very much about using a rather complicated PWA offline. But now I want to try it. However I am using links like this (inside the PWA so to say):

```
https://example.com/page.html?param=val
```

When clicking on a link like that offline in the PWA I get "This site can't be reached". This link however works fine:

```
https://example.com/page.html
```

The parameters are all handled in JavaScript in the web browser. What options do I have to handle this? Is the best perhaps to rewrite it as # links? Or do that get me into other troubles?

```
https://example.com/page.html#param=val
```

Comment: Can you add your manifest.json file and the code you used for caching GET Requests?

Comment: @Francesko Thanks, but I don't think it matters here. But maybe I should be more clear. The exact URL is cached in my case. And I think I could rewrite that in the service worker for more generic caching. However the second way might be much more easy. But I'm a bit worried about the implied scrolling (to a label named "#param").

Comment: Seems to me like a .htaccess issue not PWA

Comment: @none I don't think so, but please explain why you think that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from the cache. In your sw.js, you give the list of files you want to cache but you give the name of the file without the parameter. Which is logical as in many cases you can't know the full value of the parameters.

So in your case you cache "https://example.com/page.html" but when you call "https://example.com/page.html?param=val" the comparison fail and you get the error message.

The way to solve that is to tell the retreivng function in your sw.js file, to ignore parameter. 
Rather than

```
    caches.match(event.request)
```

just use

```
    caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true})
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I vaguely remember I did something like that at first, but I rewrote the whole caching because I had so much trouble knowing if I was doing something wrong or Chrome did not behave as I expected. So I guess the search parameters are still given to the page (i e location.href etc)?